# NextJS routing doesnt work when deployed but works when using my local server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the following url:

```
/job/engineer_123456/edit/abcde
```

Now when I run my local server: npm run dev ("next src/") then when i go to that link it works. However when I deploy my project (to firebase) then I get a 404 from that url.

I have a feeling there is a clash in the routing as my NextJS page directory structure looks like this /job is under pages):

[image]

Could it be that on production for some reason, when I go to that link, i am going to `/job/[job].js` instead of `/job/[job]/edit/[editId].js`

I am really confused why production shows a 404 page but locally it works.

Comment: huh? what has that got to do with this?

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation:

*Predefined routes take precedence over dynamic routes, and dynamic routes over catch all routes. Take a look at the following examples:*

**pages/post/create.js** - Will match /post/create

**pages/post/[pid].js** - Will match /post/1, /post/abc, etc. But not /post/create

**pages/post/[...slug].js** - Will match /post/1/2, /post/a/b/c, etc. But not /post/create, /post/abc

*Pages that are statically optimized by Automatic Static Optimization will be hydrated without their route parameters provided, i.e query will be an empty object ({}).

After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to provide the route parameters in the query object.*

So, you need to have something like:

```
pages - folder
    job - folder
        [...slug] - folder
            - index.js
            edit - folder
                - index.js
```

the slug folder will act as a "template" for all **/job/[slug]** routes which will have an index.js and also an edit page

Comment: The results then in `Error: Catch-all must be the last part of the URL.`

Comment: Sorry, as a matter of fact, since you need the **editID**, you should have [...slug.js] inside your edit folder! That would catch all IDs, and index.js would be, ideally, the index page with all the objects